# Android save state of listview with multipleChoice

Tags: java, android

I have a listview that contains some values with the multipleChoice enabled in my xml file.
I want to be able to save what has been checked by the user when the app is exited, then re-check what they have selected upon opening again. My code works for a radio group, but I can't seem to get it to work for this.

**EDIT:** Got this working by using some for loop trickery at the end.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as answered

Comment: how do you resolve your problem? regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use SharedPreferences to persist your selections.

Answer (score 1):

as @BGS wrote, SharedPreference would solve your problem. 
Check out this post: [MultiChoice Preference Widget for Android](http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240).

Here the values of the checkboxes are stored in a [special-separator]-separated string, and passed to the caller as a String array containing the selected values.

I'm using this approach, and it works great so far.